# Returning an OFFSET subquery result in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, subquery, offset

I'm selecting a random row from a table in SQLite by using a subquery to determine a random OFFSET value:

```
SELECT id, prev_node, next_node FROM edges WHERE prev_node = ? LIMIT 1
    OFFSET abs(random())%(SELECT count(*) FROM edges WHERE prev_node = ?);
```

This is functionally correct for my task, but it requires two hits to an index:

```
0|0|TABLE edges WITH INDEX edges_all_prev
0|0|TABLE edges WITH INDEX edges_all_prev
```

The query is for a random walk that is very likely to visit the same node more than once, so as the number of edges grows it would be helpful to cache the result of the `SELECT count(*)` subquery.

Can I select the value of that subquery along with my other returned values?

Looking at the VDBE dump for the query, that value is just out of reach. It's in register **8** (moved there in step 21) while the result row is being created from registers **16-18** (step 42):

```
0|Trace|0|0|0||00|
1|Integer|1|1|0||00|
2|Function|0|0|5|random(0)|00|
3|Function|0|5|4|abs(1)|01|
4|If|7|23|0||00|
5|Integer|1|7|0||00|
6|Null|0|8|0||00|
7|Integer|1|9|0||00|
8|Null|0|10|0||00|
9|Variable|2|11|1||00|
10|Goto|0|47|0||00|
11|OpenRead|2|15|0|keyinfo(4,BINARY,BINARY)|00|
12|IsNull|11|18|0||00|
13|Affinity|11|1|0|d|00|
14|SeekGe|2|18|11|1|00|
15|IdxGE|2|18|11|1|01|
16|AggStep|0|0|10|count(0)|00|
17|Next|2|15|0||00|
18|Close|2|0|0||00|
19|AggFinal|10|0|0|count(0)|00|
20|SCopy|10|13|0||00|
21|Move|13|8|1||00|
22|IfZero|9|23|-1||00|
23|Remainder|8|4|2||00|
24|MustBeInt|2|0|0||00|
25|IfPos|2|27|0||00|
26|Integer|0|2|0||00|
33|Affinity|14|1|0|d|00|
34|SeekGe|3|45|14|1|00|
35|IdxGE|3|45|14|1|01|
36|AddImm|2|-1|0||00|
37|IfNeg|2|39|0||00|
38|Goto|0|44|0||00|
39|IdxRowid|3|16|0||00|
40|Column|3|0|17||00|
41|Column|3|1|18||00|
42|ResultRow|16|3|0||00|
43|IfZero|1|45|-1||00|
44|Next|3|35|0||00|
45|Close|3|0|0||00|
46|Halt|0|0|0||00|
47|Transaction|0|0|0||00|
48|VerifyCookie|0|27|0||00|
49|TableLock|0|9|0|edges|00|
50|Goto|0|11|0||00|
```

I could create a function that saves the count after it's calculated, but is there a straightforward SQL syntax for requesting the result of that subquery?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the function to save the counts I mentioned at the end of the original post, so here's one possible answer for removing the duplicate index search. I would still like to know if this is doable with straight SQL.

I created a passthrough user function to capture the count from the
subquery as the offset is calculated.

So instead of the original query:

```
SELECT id, prev_node, next_node FROM edges WHERE prev_node = ? LIMIT 1
    OFFSET abs(random())%(
    SELECT count(*) FROM edges WHERE prev_node = ?);
```

I have something more like this:

```
SELECT id, prev_node, next_node FROM edges WHERE next_node = ? LIMIT 1
    OFFSET abs(random())%(
    cache(?, (SELECT count(*) FROM edges WHERE prev_node = ?));
```

The first argument to cache() is a unique identifier for that count. I
could just use the value of prev_node, but due to the application I
need to be able to cache the counts for forward and backward walks
separately. So I'm using "$direction:$prev_node_id" as the key.

The cache function looks like this (using Python):

```
_cache = {}
def _cache_count(self, key, count):
    self._cache[key] = count
    return count

conn.create_function("cache", 2, self._cache_count)
```

And then in the random walk function, I can cons up the hash key and
check whether the count is already known. If it is, I use a variant of
the main query that doesn't include the subquery:

```
uncached = "SELECT id, next_node, prev_node " \
    "FROM edges WHERE prev_node = :last LIMIT 1 " \
    "OFFSET abs(random())%cache(:key, " \
    "    (SELECT count(*) FROM edges WHERE prev_node = :last))"

cached = "SELECT id, next_node, prev_node, has_space, count " \
    "FROM edges WHERE prev_node = :last LIMIT 1 " \
    "OFFSET abs(random())%:count"

key = "%s:%s" % (direction, last_node)
if key in cache:
    count = cache[key]
    query = cached
    args = dict(last=last_node, count=count)
else:
    query = uncached
    args = dict(last=last_node, key=key)

row = c.execute(query, args).fetchone()
```

The cached queries run about twice as fast as the uncached on average (5.7us
vs. 10.9us).

Comment: What's the overhead in the Python exception handling?  Is it noticeably faster to do `cache.has_key(key)` (or just `cache.get(key)` and check for `None`) in the uncached case?

Comment: Good question! I just tested this with a million cache hits and a million misses on a dictionary with a million integer keys. I tried four options: `try/except`, `has_key`, `cache.get(key)`, and `key in cache`. `try/except` has excellent performance when the key exists, but it's _4x_ worse than the next on a miss. `key in cache` has the best average performance for my use.